# Stop a function from running and call it again

Tags: python, multithreading, function

I want go() to continuously run when the function main is called. When the function main is called again I want go() to "reset" by stopping its execution and re-starting it. For instance:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
def main():
     global run
     if run==True:
         running=False
         run=False
     def go():
         i=0
         global run
         run=True
         while running:
             print(i+=1) 
             time.sleep(1)
     t = Thread(target = go)
     running=True
     t.start()


run=False
main()
time.sleep(3)
main()
```

This is an example where the code continuously prints 0-infinity. When the function main is called again I want to halt the execution and restart it from i=0. This example however doesn't work, and two instances of go() are being run.(So there are two print(i+=1) every second)

Comment: what is the error in this code ? what do you want ?

Comment: There is no error. After calling the function a second time, I would like the thread to stop being run, and a new thread to start. However, in the second code shown above, two run at the same time.

Comment: Hi, Please modify your question to properly expose the problem you want people help to solve. A good question includes such information, what you want to do, how you did it, and what you get. Best

Comment: Sorry, Im having trouble explaining it

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
from threading import Thread
import time
def main(arg = None):
     def go():
         global run
         run=True
         while run:
             print("running") 
             time.sleep(1)
     global run
     if run==True:
         run=False
         t = arg
         t.join()

     t = Thread(target = go)
     t.start()
     return t

run=False
t = main()
time.sleep(3)
main(t)
```